# GoLang's time.Date does not throw error for days beyond valid days in a month

Tags: date, go, time

I am trying to construct a GoLang `time.Date()` instance from the input I get; something like:

```
time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

Where 'year' 'month' and 'day' are read from a file.
It works fine for most of the cases, however if I pass "2000-01-32" it automatically interprets as "2000-02-01" [Example in The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Gd4-xjPlhgb).

Is there a way to force returning error instead of carry over the day in a case like abovr?

Thanks.

Comment: No. The time.Date [documentation](https://godoc.org/time#Date) says: *The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For example, October 32 converts to November 1.*

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you can compare parsed value to given parameters. Unless normalized, they should be same.

```
func parse(year, month, day int) (time.Time, bool) {
  t := time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
  y, m, d := t.Date()
  return t, y == year && int(m) == month && d == day
}
```

In action: https://play.golang.org/p/UJYszuyJwnx